# Get return from AsyncTask

Tags: android, api, web-services

I'm trying to get a return value from the InBackground method in a way that it fetches the first time, returns right but after returns NULL, my logic was as follows: inside the onPostExecute method I call another function to set the value of a variable , however for some reason this variable becomes NULL, after receiving the data correctly. Here is my code:

```
 public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

Button btnEntrada, btnCarregamento, btnDescarregamento;
EditText numberOF;
TextView txt;

private AlertDialog alert;
private Boolean isOnline;
private JSONArray jsonArray;
private String url = "http://192.168.1.5/ws/entradaSetor.php?numberOF=";
private MyTask task = new MyTask();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    btnEntrada = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnEntrada);
    btnCarregamento = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnCarregamento);
    btnDescarregamento = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnDescarregamento);
    numberOF = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.numberOFText);

    btnEntrada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (numberOF.getText().toString().compareTo("") == 0) {
                alertDialog("la");
            } else {
                conecta(numberOF.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });

}
private void alertDialog(String numero){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Atenção");
    builder.setMessage(numero);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private void func_EntryQuantity(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    final EditText edittext = new EditText(HomeActivity.this);
    alert.setMessage("\nQuantidade Recebida na OF");
    alert.setTitle("Digite a quantidade recebida");

    alert.setView(edittext);

    alert.setPositiveButton("CONFIRMAR ENTRADA", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Editable YouEditTextValue = edittext.getText();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("VOLTAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}

private Boolean verifica(){
    if(this.jsonArray.length() == 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

private void conecta(String numberOF){
    task.execute(url + numberOF);
}

private void entradaSetor(JSONArray jsonArray){
    this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection myConnection =
                    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                InputStream responseBody = myConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader responseBodyReader =
                        new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8");

                BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String inputStr;
                while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                    responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseStrBuilder.toString());

                //myConnection.disconnect();
                return jsonArray;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        // Call activity method with results
        entradaSetor(jsonArray);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you provide your log

Comment: @Bruno any feedback after the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that a better way to provide result back to the calling code is to use an interface, like for instance:

```
interface RequestListener {
   public onResultSuccess(JSONArray array);
   public onResultFail(String error);
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray>
{
    RequestListener listener = null;

    MyTask(RequestListener listener) {
       this.listener = listener
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection myConnection =
                    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                InputStream responseBody = myConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader responseBodyReader =
                        new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8");

                BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String inputStr;
                while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                    responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseStrBuilder.toString());

                //myConnection.disconnect();
                return jsonArray;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        if (listener != null) {
           if (jsonArray != null) {
              listener.onResultSuccess(jsonArray);
           } else {
              listener.onResultFail(your-message);
           }
        } 
    }
}
```

then of course you have to provide an instance of the `RequestListener` interface when you instantiate the `MyTask` object (might be inside the `onCreate`)

Comment: I tested this and it worked, however I put what I needed into the onPostExecute method that called it and it worked. Thank you!